# Downloading large data from PostgreSQL DB using WFS request in Shape-zip format using GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, wfs

I am using GeoServer 2.18.0 on CentOS 7 & it's deployed under Tomcat 9.

- We have few large spatial tables in our PostgreSQL/PostGIS database (those table has spatial index and vacuumed)
- Using WFS request end-users downloading data as 'Shape-zip format'.
- If file size reaches up to 2 GB then request gets crashed tried to find its max. limit & based on [geosolution site][1] article max. limit is 2 GB.

My Questions :

1. How to handle large data requests in GeoServer for 'shape-zip' format ?
2. Can we increase max. limit for shapefile ?
3. If not then what's the alternate options ? (thinking to use GeoJSON format)

[1]: [https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/educational/en/vector_data/otherformats.html#:~:text=Only%20one%20geometry%20type%20per,should%20the%20limit%20be%20exceeded](https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/educational/en/vector_data/otherformats.html#:%7E:text=Only%20one%20geometry%20type%20per,should%20the%20limit%20be%20exceeded))

Comment: You can't increase the max size https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/shapefiles/geoprocessing-considerations-for-shapefile-output.htm.  Use GML that is the standard format for WFS, or GeoJSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The max limit for a shapefile it's 2GB because offsets in the files are specified with a 32bit integer, in other words, the limit is structural due to the file format.

When downloading shape-zip larger than 2GB GeoServer should split the data into multiple shapefiles, there is logic ensuring that, but in your case, there might be an issue with how offsets are calculated. Try setting the following system variable in the JVM running GeoServer to a value smaller than 2GB, that should handle give it a more breathing room and avoid corner cases, e.g.:

```
java ... -DGS_SHP_MAX_SIZE=1900000000
```

Streaming formats like GML, GeoJSON or CSV have no size limit, althouth the HTTP connection might time out on you if used for prolonged time (that is dependent on the network hw/sw between the client and GeoServer).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One additional question :  On what basis Geo-server splits the file into small pieces ? ('attribute' level or 'size' level) it's not clear to me.

Comment: It's based on the bytes that the next geometry will use in the shp file, or the next row in the dbf file will use. If it exceeds the limit, a new shapefile is allocated.